# Change HTTP response status code in NextJs 14 App Router

Tags: javascript, next.js

Recently, I have had to change the HTTP response status code for certain requests within my Next.js 14 App Router project, and the truth is that it has been quite complicated for me because I implement Internationalization and other functionalities.

Following the logic of the order of execution of the request in Nextjs, I used the middleware to create a new response using NextResponse, passing it the HTTP status code that it needed.

I came up with this solution:

```
export default async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
    const { pathname } = request.nextUrl

    const handleI18nRouting = createMiddleware({
        locales,
        defaultLocale,
        localePrefix,
        localeDetection,
        pathnames
    });

    let responseLang = handleI18nRouting(request);
    
    if (![307, 308].includes(responseLang.status)) {
        let status = { status: responseLang.status} 
        if(pathname==="path_to_be_validated"){
          status.status = 410
        }
        return NextResponse.next({ ...status, headers: responseLang.headers })
    } else {
        return responseLang
    }
}
```

I would like to know another way to do it using Next.js 14 App Router inside the page or changing it in the not-found.